# Using Python numpy where condition to change entires below a certain value

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, where-clause

Here's my array:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([0, 5.0, 0, 5.0, 5.0])
```

Is it possible to use `numpy.where` in some way to add a value `x` to all those entires in `a` that are less than `l`?

So something like:

```
a = a[np.where(a < 5).add(2.5)]
```

Should return:

```
array([2.5, 5.0, 2.5, 5.0, 5.0])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
a = np.array([0., 5., 0., 5., 5.])
a[np.where(a < 5)] += 2.5
```

in case you really want to use `where` or just

```
a[a < 5] += 2.5
```

which I usually use for these kind of operations.

Answer (score 4):

You could use [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) to create the array of *additions* and then simply add to `a` -

```
a + np.where(a < l, 2.5,0)
```

Sample run -

```
In [16]: a = np.array([1, 5, 4, 5, 5])

In [17]: l = 5

In [18]: a + np.where(a < l, 2.5,0)
Out[18]: array([ 3.5,  5. ,  6.5,  5. ,  5. ])
```

Comment: Just wanted to highlight that this is the only answers (except mine :-)) that works if the dtypes are too different (`int` += `float`) to allow in-place addition.

Answer (score 4):

Given that you probably **need to change the dtype** (from `int` to `float`) you need to create a new array. A simple way without explicit `.astype` or `np.where` calls is multiplication with a mask:

```
>>> b = a + (a < 5) * 2.5
>>> b
array([ 2.5,  5. ,  2.5,  5. ,  5. ])
```

with [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html#numpy.where) this can be changed to a simple expression (using the `else`-condition, third argument, in `where`):

```
>>> a = np.where(a < 5, a + 2.5, a)
>>> a
array([ 2.5,  5. ,  2.5,  5. ,  5. ])
```

Comment: thanks for pointing out the mistake with the type. It should be float.

Comment: @AnthonyW That's why we talk of `representative` sample when posting questions :)

Answer (score 1):

```
a += np.where(a < 1, 2.5, 0)
```

`where` will return the second argument wherever the condition (first argument) is satisfied and the third argument otherwise.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a "masked array" as an index. Boolean operations, such as `a < 1` return such an array.

```
>>> a<1
array([False, False, False, False, False], dtype=bool)
```

you can use it as

```
>>> a[a<1] += 1
```

The `a<1` part selects only the items in `a` that match the condition. You can operate on this part only then.

If you want to keep a trace of your selection, you can proceed in two steps.

```
>>> mask = a>1
>>> a[mask] += 1
```

Also, you can count the items matching the conditions:

```
>>> print np.sum(mask)
```